# https in WCF Test Client Using basicHttpBinding binding

Tags: wcf, web-services, service, https, client

I need to know what changes I need to make for the following web.config to show up in WCF Test Client.  I am looking to see a web.config that invokes an ssl, https protocol. I would like the application to show  up in WCF Test Client without the metadata errors.  By the way, I tried mexHttpsBinding  and getting rid of  httpGetEnabled="False".  Neither worked.  I have also tried creating an https endpoint--no joy.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

```
<services>

  <service name="WcfService1_ssl.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="OhBehave">

    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1_ssl.IService1" bindingConfiguration="secureBinding" />

    <!-- VERIFY:  Verify address="mex" section is commented or deleted to avoid any mexHttpBinding. -->

    <endpoint address="mex"   binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />

  </service>

</services>

<behaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>

    <behavior name="OhBehave">

      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646" />

      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="False"  httpsGetEnabled="True" />

      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />

    </behavior>

  </serviceBehaviors>

</behaviors>

<bindings>

  <basicHttpBinding>

    <clear />

    <binding name="secureBinding" closeTimeout="10:00:00" openTimeout="10:00:00" receiveTimeout="10:10:00" sendTimeout="10:10:00" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"

             hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2147483647"

             maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" messageEncoding="Text">

      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" />

      <security mode="Transport">

        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>

      </security>

    </binding>

  </basicHttpBinding>

</bindings>

<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"  aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
```

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can test https using [soapUI](http://www.soapui.org/), dont think https is supported by wcf test client